# Convert Array into Single Object using Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I convert an array into a list of objects?

Turn

```
[
    {
        "currenttime":43481.46983805556,
        "moped":"30 minutes",
        "car":"1 hour"
    }
]
```

into

```
{
    "currenttime":43481.46983805556,
    "moped":"30 minutes",
    "car":"1 hour"
}
```

The data is retrieved from an external source and then the data edited using Vue.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {   
        items: []
    },
    created: function() {
        fetch('https://example.com/delivery.json')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(items => {        
            this.items = items
        })
    }
    });
</script>
```

I had originally tried to output using an expression of `{{ items.car }}` and `{{ items.0.car }}` with no success

Comment: What's the difference between `array` and `list of objects`? What if you receive an array with two objects, do you want only the first one (meaning `items[0]`)?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but it's *a* problem: You're not handling errors in your `fetch` call, in two different ways: 1. You're not handling errors at all (you need to either add a `catch` handler, or propagate the promise to something that will have a `catch` handler), and 2. You're not checking `.ok`. Its' not just you, this second one is such a common mistake that [I wrote it up in my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: Use v-for instead of getting single object

Comment: You need to show us your Vue HTML template. Use something like `<div v-for="item in items">{{ item.car }}</div>` instead of ditching the rest of the array.

Comment: There is only 1 object (line of data) at all times. But the external code that creates the JSON places it in an array. I am actually using this data within Wordpress using Vue, so doing it this way [rather than v-for] makes it a little easier in the WP templates. The solution below (although not perfect as someone has flagged) has solved this. Thanks to all who commented

Answer (score 1):

Adding this, although not an ideal or correct solution does solve the issue for now.

`this.items = items[0]`